# How to update a property of a custom UITableViewCell on didSelectRowAtIndex?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that is made up of a number of custom `UITableViewCells`.

When the table `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method fires, if the `indexPath.row` is equal to 2, I want to update a `UILabel` within the cell at this row.

My thinking was to use something along the following lines;

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if(indexPath.row == 2){

    myCustomCellView *cell = [self.essentialsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.myUILabel.text = @"my text";

    [tableView reloadData];

  }
}
```

The problem here is that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` returns an object of type `UITableViewCell`, not `myCustomCellView`.

Can anyone advise how i might access and update properties of cells within the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method?

Answer (score 0):

Define one Bool value say "secondRowIsClicked". Set it to No in your `viewWillApper` or `viewDidAppear` function.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if(indexPath.row == 2)
    {
        secondRowIsClicked = YES;
        [tableView reloadData];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // Your code
   if (secondRowIsClicked == YES)
   {
       cell.myUILabel.text = @"my text";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with bellow code..

```
myCustomCellView *cell = (myCustomCellView *) [self.essentialsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

you can reload `UITableViewCell` with its `indexPath` like bellow..

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Comment: @Scratcha hey if this answer is useful to you then please accept and upvote the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 myCustomCellView *cell = [self.essentialsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
 UILabel *yourLabel=[cell.contentViews.subviews viewWithTag:indexPath.row+1];
 //do whatever you want with your label;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // Your code
          cell.myUILabel.text = @"my text";
          cell.myUILabel.tag=indexpath.row+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

typecast `UITableViewCell` to your custom cell

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(indexPath.row == 2){

        myCustomCellView *cell = (myCustomCellView *)[self.essentialsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.myUILabel.text = @"my text";

        [tableView reloadData];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to upadte the datasoure and den call the reload the tableview

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
if(indexPath.row == 2){

    //update the array which is used as the data provider  in cell for row at index path.

    [tableView reloadData];

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`myCustomCellView` is a subClass of `UITableViewCell`.
So just typcast the cell

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(indexPath.row == 2){

        myCustomCellView *cell = (myCustomCellView *)[self.essentialsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.myUILabel.text = @"my text";

        [tableView reloadData];

      }
    }
```

*More info:
As per Apple coding guide lines do not user class name start with lower case letter
instead of `myCustomCellView` use `MyCustomCellView`*